# Catching exceptions from static fields in the main class

Tags: java, exception, static

I never really thought about this before but looking at the following code

```
public class SomeJavaProgram {

    private static String runMe() {
        throw new RuntimeException("hi tadsfasdf");
    }
    private static String name = runMe();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi there.");
    }
}
```

I never did statics like this in a main before but then I entered scala, and if you have subclasses that start adding defs, exceptions can be thrown before main is even called.

So, in java(not scala), is there a way to catch these exceptions(if I am the superclass and subclasses end up having a static field that throws an exception or static initializer block)....how can I catch all these?

I of course do rely on ONE single definition not throwing which is the

```
private Logger log = createLoggerFromSomeLoggingLib();
```

But after that, ideally I would want all exceptions to be logged to the logged file rather than stderr.

That said, I am glad I have always kept the stderr/stdout files along with my logging files now.

Comment: There's no way to consistently do this. You'd have to wrap the first access to any class, ie. when the class is initialized, with a try-catch everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure, but obviously this can be resolved, very easily, by only *defining* your members inside the `main` method. This is the coding convention I usually go with.

Comment: @christopher my coding converion is main always does new App().start() and no statics in the the main class so I typically avoid it as well.  scala is different and subclass applications(the real application) extending our CompanyApp trait can throw and they don't get caught.

Answer (score 4):

Use the static initializer:

```
private static String name;

static {
    try {
        name = runMe();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the subclasses that extend me and have statics

Comment: I really kind of need a registration hook to register as the first thing.

Comment: Dean, what would you do if initialization of static field fails in one of the subclasses? Think about it for a second, I'm guessing that there is nothing that you can do. You don't know what the field is for, so you don't know how to handle/recover from failure. You would like to register a hook for a situation when class initialization fails? You can use reflection (Class.forName) to load the class and handle the resulting ClassDefNotFound, but do you know all subclasses that will occur at runtime?

Comment: eh, I was hoping just to get a log.warning(exc, "Server startup failed") out the door is all.  Nope, don't know subclasses ahead of time.  this issue is more common in scala when people define fields in subclasses that call methods that could throw exceptions and that won't exist now in our log files.  in java, I never hit that situation before.